# How do I use :not and find () together in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to have :not and find() together, i tried in many ways but in vain .
I basically  need to select iterate through all the children of a particular div **without tabindex** attribute.

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: can u please provide me the syntax

Comment: Why not rephrase the question to:  "How do I use `:not` and `find` together?" ?

Comment: I am having issues when using attribute name in not(), $('#div1').find(':not('[tabindex]')') is having issues

Comment: So which issue???...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#div1').find(':not([tabindex])').addClass('red')
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1'>

<span>red</span>
<span tabindex='1'>123</span>



</div>
```

Use `$('#div1').find(':not([tabindex])')`

Comment: @NivinRai glad to help happy coding :)